# DNS not working on 22.04 server

Tags: network-manager, dns, 22.04, usb-modem

I have a new Ubuntu 22.04 server build on a Raspberry Pi with a Sierra Aircard 320U USB modem providing internet access. Network Mamager is installed as is Modem Manager. I built the system and configured the modem with ethernet connected.

When I removed the Ethernet, and rebooted, the internet access works through the modem but not DNS.  I can ping the IP address of Google but not google.com. 'resolvectl status' shows a link for the modem device but with 'Current Scope: none'. 'nmcli con show gsm', where 'gsm' is the name the connection gets, shows the correct IP4.ADDRESS, IP4.DNS[1] etc.

When I type the command 'sudo dhclient' to manually restart the lease, the DNS starts working. 'resolvectl status' now shows Current Scope: DNS, and the correct network DNS addresses.

I haven't had this problem on earlier Ubuntu version builds but they do have other functions such as OpenVPN running.

My question is, what configuration item do I need to make the DHCP configuration work without the manual intervention? Is my problem a result of a change in 22.04?  I have been scouring forums and manuals for clues but so far the problem persists. I am sure I have missed something obvious and simple so would appreciate a pointer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid I don't have a definitive answer to why after much research. I think the modem is an ancient one so it is possible NetworkManager or systemd-resolved are not compatible. The NetworkManager warning 'modem IP method unsupported', reported by journalctl, is a clue.

A simple way to bypass the problem and get a DNS when using the modem for internet access is to provide a systemd fallback DNS. Something like Google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

In /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
change the line #FallbackDNS=
to FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

This works with NetworkManager as the renderer of the modem and otherwise default configuration.